# OpenVPN stays on fallback network when primary returns

Tags: networking, router, vpn, routing, openvpn

I have a server running OpenVPN client through a Netgear 2120 device.  The Netgear accepts a primary WAN, in this case a cable/broadband connection and also provides a second internet connection via a 4G connection.  When the cable connection is up, it provides the internet service.  When it goes down, the Netgear falls back on the 4G connection.  The already-established OpenVPN connection switches over as well.  When the WAN comes back up, I can log on to the server and see my external connection coming from the cable, but the OpenVPN stays on the slower 4G connection unless the 4G becomes unavailable.  Restarting the OpenVPN service from either end fixes it.  Is there way to have this happen automatically?

OpenVPN client is running on a Raspberry Pi, plugged into a Cradlepoint 1200B router, with the WAN port of the router plugged into the Netgear device.  As usual, the 4G IP address is NAT'd, so you can't access devices from outside - this is why I have the VPN.  The theory this makes the external IP address irrelevant.   The Pi is tunneling through the Cradlepoint, Netgear, and Internet to connect to the OpenVPN server.

Aside from the changes to customize the Wifi name and password, the Cradlepoint is running with its factory defaults.

Open VPN server is using tcp.   Client has the "nobind" option in it, but the server does not.

Options in server configuration file (leaving out the security-related options like encryption and certificate information):

```
proto tcp 
keepalive 30 180
persist-key
persist-tun
```

And in the client config:

```
proto tcp
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
```

Comment: We probably need to know a lot more about your router config and router model.  (Also, is your OpenVPN config on the router or server?)  Are you using UDP or TCP for your connection?   Not sure if these will help, but you might be able to get the desired behaviour using the "nobind" and "float" options.   (Particularly the nobind one)

Comment: Is does appear that once a connection is established ,the LB2120 continues to route that connection through whatever interface is started with until that interface fails.